# GeoDjango + PostGIS: pure geometry SRID

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

I am thinking about using django (2.0.6) with Postgres/postGIS as a backend (10/2.4?).

However, the model geometries I intend to use will not be stored "against" a spheroid (whether earth mars, etc) or any other kind of SRID. Rather a 100% pure geometry in 3D cartesian coordinates, where 1 unit = 1 meter.

How am I to declare model fields and insure they are pure geometry both:

- at database level
- at application level

Would this work?

```
geometry = models.MultiPolygonField(_('Geometry'), spatial_index=True, dim=3)
```

Or better to set the SRID?:

```
geometry = models.MultiPolygonField(_('Geometry'), spatial_index=True, dim=3, srid=0)
```

Many thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64252/postgis-spatial-reference-id-srid-for-regular-cartesian-coordinate-system

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SRID 3857](https://epsg.io/3857) for 1m Cartesian grid:

`models.py`:

```
class Place(models.Model):
    geom = models.PointField(srid=3857, dim=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.geom.coords)
```

However, GeoDjango does not support 3d distance calculations out of the box. For example:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import Distance

from myapp.models import Place

p = Point(100, 100, 0)

Place.objects.create(geom=p)
Place.objects.create(geom=Point(150, 100, 0))
Place.objects.create(geom=Point(100, 100, 22))
Place.objects.create(geom=Point(100, 100, 500))
Place.objects.create(geom=Point(150, 150, 0))
Place.objects.create(geom=Point(250, 250, 0))

for o in Place.objects.filter(geom__distance_lte=(p, Distance(m=100))):
    print(o.geom.coords, p.distance(o.geom))
```

Output:

```
(100.0, 100.0, 0.0) 0.0
(150.0, 100.0, 0.0) 50.0
(100.0, 100.0, 22.0) 0.0
(100.0, 100.0, 500.0) 0.0
(150.0, 150.0, 0.0) 70.71067811865476
```

In pure PostGIS, compare `ST_Distance` and `ST_3DDistance` :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT
         "myapp_place"."id",
         ST_Distance("myapp_place"."geom",
                     ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=3857;POINT(100 100 0)')) d,
         ST_AsEWKT("myapp_place"."geom")

       FROM "myapp_place"
     ) t
WHERE d <= 100.0
```

vs.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT
         "myapp_place"."id",
         ST_3DDistance("myapp_place"."geom",
                     ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=3857;POINT(100 100 0)')) d,
         ST_AsEWKT("myapp_place"."geom")

       FROM "myapp_place"
     ) t
WHERE d <= 100.0
```